# Trigger not working for stopping table insert

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the following code for stopping null value insert into table using trigger. But when I pass null value, the inserting is happening fine. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

```
create table test
(col1 number,
 col2 varchar2(40)
 )

create or replace trigger test_trg
after insert on test
for each row
declare
    excp exception;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    if :new.col2 is null then
     RAISE excp;
    end if;
exception
    when excp then
         dbms_output.put_line('error');
         rollback;
end;
```

(Please note, I do accept that using a not null or a check constraint on the col2 is a better solution. I just want to find out the reason behind the error in this seemingly correct code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rollback in trigger, just re-raise excpetion after logging it:

```
create or replace trigger test_trg
after insert on test
for each row
declare
    excp exception;
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    if :new.col2 is null then
     RAISE excp;
    end if;
exception
    when excp then
         dbms_output.put_line('error');
         raise; -- propagate error
end;
```

When you put "exception ... end;" block in code you say to PL/SQL that  managing consequences of this error is on your responsibility. So, if you don't raise any error from a code which handles original error, for PL/SQL it means that all actions regarding this error already done in your code, all went OK and record must be inserted.

You can try it in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bf78/4).

Comment: Thank you very much thinkJet for the help. That solved the issue :).... BTW the SQLFiddle is a great one, I did not know about it ... thanks for that too :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the trigger as `BEFORE INSERT` to fire before the insert is executed, remove the `pragma autonomouse_transaction` and the `rollback` (they have no sense here, because you do not any DML), then reraise the exception in the exception handler

Comment: Actually initially I made it as BEFORE INSERT only. But that did not work. And I thought that was logical. If I define as BEFORE INSERT, then this will execute before the actual table insertion. So how then will the rollback achieve anything before the data has been inserted. Hence changed it to a AFTER INSERT.

Comment: why do you have `pragma autonomous_transaction;` and `rollback;` inside the trigger?

Comment: Rollback is there as a passive way to prevent the insertion. And you can not perform commit, rollback inside a trigger, as trigger is not a separate transaction. To do that you need a autonomous transaction inside which rollback/commit will happen.

Comment: `autonomous_transaction` is a new transaction, it has nothing to do with the INSERT, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel for the help. That solved the issue :)